# Conversion of SAM to BAM files

Tags: samtools, genomics, format-conversion, bowtie2

I am very new to micro RNA analysis. I have been using H. sapiens, GRCh38 + major index as given in the Bowtie Website to align with my trimmed FASTQ file .
The command I am using to make very sensitive alignments with Bowtie2 is given below.

```
module load  Bowtie2; 
bowtie2 --local -p 8 -q --phred33 -D 20 -R 3 -N 0 -L 8 \
    -i S,1,0.50 -x grch38_1kgmaj \
    -U /gpfs/ycga/scratch60/nicoli/ag2646/HumanmicroRNAbowtie_verysensitive_1.06.2021./3kPa_HDF_miRNA_1bbduk.fastq \
    -S /gpfs/ycga/scratch60/nicoli/ag2646/HumanmicroRNAbowtie_verysensitive_1.06.2021./3kPa_HDF_miRNA_1bbduk.sam
```

Then I am using:

```
samtools sort -bS 3kPa_HDF_miRNA_1bbduk.sam > 3kPa_HDF_miRNA_1bbduk.bam
```

to convert sam files into bam files.

However, I am hitting the error described below:

```
[W::sam_read1_sam] Parse error at line 46371
```

When I grepped the specific line it shows:

```
SRR8248790.46371        4       *       0       0       *       *       0       0       CCTGGATGATGATAAGCAAATGCTGACTGAACATGAAGGTCTTAATTAGCTCTAACTGACTAGATCGGAAGAGCAC   BBADAGEHIFHHIIIIIGGFIHIIIIIIIHHHHHIHHHEHEHEHFEHIIIEHIIIIIEHIIHIIIHGHHHIIII1C   YT:Z:UU
```

Any specific help troubleshooting this error will be very useful.

Comment: The `[W:` is just a warning. If the process errored out, there should be another actual error message that follows that warning.

Comment: Is it the last line of the samfile? I wonder if the sam file could be truncated (like a missing newline or something).

Comment: How did you "grep the line"? Is that actually line number 46371 of the file, or is that a random line that happens to contain the string `46371`?

Comment: Is your `samtools sort` command actually a `samtools view` command? The `-bS` flag would not work with `samtools sort`: http://www.htslib.org/doc/samtools-sort.html. I tried it out of curiosity and got `samtools: invalid option -- b`.

Comment: See similar situation here: https://www.biostars.org/p/169277/. Have you confirmed that bowtie2 finished without errors? Does your sam file look ok? how many lines does it have?

Comment: My bowtie file alignment completed without truncation but only showed errros.

Comment: Are you able to trace the same line in the raw fastq file (before trimming) with the same identifier?? If yes, what is the content of that line?

Comment: I have resolved all the errors. Thanks for all your help.